# What is the real code behind digital clocks? Java

Tags: java, time, clock

I know it's kind of naive question, and maybe out of place, but I was really wondering the secret behind the functionality that is used to calculate the right timing for seconds, minutes, and hours in computers? Since, as you know, computer doesn't create things by itself, and numbers doesn't increase in a certain time while adding ones, but somehow, it does in this case? Could anyone explain how exactly? Maybe provide some java code to make a better understanding of how it's implemented to a computer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more suited to the Electrical Engineering site.

Comment: One of the more common methods is the [Quartz clock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartz_clock), but I wouldn't say I'm qualified enough to explain it in great enough detail.

Comment: Read this article on [real time clocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_clock). Afterwards, please read the [Stack Overflow Help File](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These systems generally rely on a [Real Time Clock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_clock).

This is a hardware device that uses a `quartz crystal`, that keeps track of time, and often draws next to no current, and can remain counting on nothing more then a button cell for a few years.

Devices like GPS location devices will rely on the GPS signal for time.

Still they way these devices functions is by having a VERY precise crystal that oscillated at a known frequency, these ticks are then counted to calculate a time.

In the event of drift, the next time the system boots and talks to a time server, it may update the value on the RTC.

Answer (score 1):

The clock itself is implemented as hardware. The software itself only reads the value provided by the clockcircuit.